# data arrangement in R

Tags: r

my dataset looks like this

```
destaddr:192.168.0   srcaddr:231.19.0.1  protocol:8
destaddr:192.168.0   srcaddr:231.19.0.1  protocol:8
destaddr:192.168.0   srcaddr:231.19.0.1  protocol:8
```

I want my dataset in this form in rstudio:

```
destaddr         srcaddr            protocol
192.168.0        231.19.0.1             8
192.168.0        231.19.0.1             8
192.168.0        231.19.0.1             8
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO! What about something like this using base `R`, replacing letters and "`:`" with nothing, creating a `data.frame` like this:

```
new_df <- data.frame (
           destadd = gsub('[a-z]+:', '', df$V1),
           srcaddr = gsub('[a-z]+:', '', df$V2),
           protocol= gsub('[a-z]+:', '', df$V3)
                     )

new_df
    destadd    srcaddr protocol
1 192.168.0 231.19.0.1        8
2 192.168.0 231.19.0.1        8
3 192.168.0 231.19.0.1        8
```

Or, you can make it more shorter, using the advice of Ankur Sinha in the comment:

```
new_df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) gsub("[a-z]+:","", x)))
colnames(new_df) <-  c('destaddr','srcaddr','protocol')
```

---

With data:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'destaddr:192.168.0   srcaddr:231.19.0.1  protocol:8
destaddr:192.168.0   srcaddr:231.19.0.1  protocol:8
destaddr:192.168.0   srcaddr:231.19.0.1  protocol:8', header = F)
```

Comment: One liner for your solution: `new_df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) gsub("[a-z]+:","", x)))` :) May be you can edit and add this.

Comment: @AnkurSinha thanks, first of all! I had thought about it, but it's not giving exactly what OP needs, because the colnames are generic V1... Vn. However it's a good solution. But it can be modified adding a second line with `colnames()`.

Comment: Totally. It also depends what his current columns looks like, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `splitstackshape` package to achieve this easily, especially if you have the pattern in much more than 3 columns:

```
library(splitstackshape)
newdf <- cSplit(df, 1:ncol(df), sep = ":", direction = "long")
```

Now remove the unnecessary alternate rows:

```
newdf <- newdf[-(seq(1, nrow(newdf), 2)), ]
```

Final Output:

```
destaddr         srcaddr            protocol
192.168.0        231.19.0.1             8
192.168.0        231.19.0.1             8
192.168.0        231.19.0.1             8
```

---

Sample dataset:

```
destaddr <- c('destaddr:192.168.0', 'destaddr:192.168.0', 'destaddr:192.168.0')
srcaddr <- c('srcaddr:231.19.0.1', 'srcaddr:231.19.0.1', 'srcaddr:231.19.0.1')
protocol <- c('protocol:8', 'protocol:8', 'protocol:8')
df <- data.frame(destaddr, srcaddr, protocol)
```